# what is the difference about import import {} import * as in typescript

Tags: typescript

when I write code using typescript, sometimes import module using type 1:

```
import foo from bar;
```

sometimes import using type 2:

```
import {foo} from bar;
```

sometimes import using type 3:

```
import * as foo from bar;
```

what is the difference? when should using type 1,2,3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import foo from bar;
```

works when in bar you do

```
export default .... // when exporting, there is no restriction about naming. You can `export default foo` but `import bar from bar`
```

```
import { foo } from bar; // this is more restriced, and you need to precisely import the same name as you export
```

works when you do

```
export const foo .....
```

And regarding

```
import * as foo from bar
```

It basically takes everything that is exported from `bar` and allows you to use it like this:

```
import * as foo from bar


foo.bar
foo.somethingElse

// bar

export const bar = ...
export const somethingElse...
```